# How to merge changes between core data background context and main context in Swift

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, core-data

I've got a MacOS app that imports data from CSV into Core Data. Since it can be a long running process I opted to do the import in a background thread so I can update the UI with the import progress. So, to avoid optimistic locking failures when saving changes to the persistent store, I merge changes on save between the background context and the main context.

I don't think I'm handling the merge changes properly, because when I call save on the background context, it then calls a merge changes function which BLOCKS the UI. Is there not a way to merge changes between contexts without blocking the UI?

Here's how I create the background context which I call moc2:

```
let app = NSApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
let container = app.persistentContainer
        container.performBackgroundTask(){ (moc2) in
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self.app, selector: #selector(self.app.handleBackgroundCoreDataChangeInMainManagedContext(notification:)), name: NSNotification.Name.NSManagedObjectContextDidSave, object: moc2)
//perform import...
self.save(moc2: moc2)
}
```

And the save function:

```
func save(moc2: NSManagedObjectContext){
    do {
        try moc2.save()
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

And here's the merge changes selector in AppDelegate:

```
@objc func handleBackgroundCoreDataChangeInMainManagedContext(notification: Notification){
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.managedObjectContext?.mergeChanges(fromContextDidSave: notification)
    }
}
```

Is there a way to merge changes without blocking the UI using DispatchQueue.main.async?

Answer (score -1):

I tested a new function in AppDelegate that gets the context from the notification's object, and then executes mergeChanges asynchronously on that context's thread. This at least doesn't block the UI. I'll see if changes are persisting though after some future testing.

```
@objc func handleBackgroundCoreDataChangeInMainManagedContext(notification: Notification){
    if let moc2 = notification.object as? NSManagedObjectContext {
        moc2.perform {
            moc2.mergeChanges(fromContextDidSave: notification)
        }
    }
}
```